# Cocoa CGImage save corrupts image, but NSImageView display is okay

Tags: swift, cocoa, png, cgimage

I'm writing a scanner app using ImageCaptureCore, and I'm able to construct the returned image into a `CGImage` and (via `NSImage`) display that in an `NSImageView`. The image is 8-bit grayscale.  A screenshot looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of NSImageView with good image]

But when I save the `CGImage` as PNG and open that in Preview, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of corrupted saved image]

The code I use to save looks like this:

```swift
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/tp/image.png")
if let img = self.imageView.image?.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil),
    let dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, kUTTypePNG, 1, nil)
{
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, img, nil)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest)
}
```

I also tried saving using `NSBitmapImageRep`, as both PNG and TIFF, and I get the same results. The code to create the `CGImage` looks like:

```swift
guard
    let data = inBandData.dataBuffer,
    let provider = CGDataProvider(data: data as CFData)
else
{
    debugLog("No scan data returned or unable to create data provider")
    return
}

let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
let bmInfo: CGBitmapInfo = [.byteOrder32Little]
if let image = CGImage(width: inBandData.fullImageWidth,
                    height: inBandData.fullImageHeight,
                    bitsPerComponent: inBandData.bitsPerComponent,    // 8
                    bitsPerPixel: inBandData.bitsPerPixel,            // 8
                    bytesPerRow: inBandData.fullImageWidth, //inBandData.bytesPerRow, because e.g., bytesPerRow is 830, image width is 827.
                    space: colorSpace,
                    bitmapInfo: bmInfo,
                    provider: provider,
                    decode: nil,
                    shouldInterpolate: true,
                    intent: .defaultIntent)
{
    let size = NSSize(width: inBandData.fullImageWidth, height: inBandData.fullImageHeight)
    self.imageView.image = NSImage(cgImage: image, size: size)
    .
    .
    .
}
```

It looks like maybe endianness is wrong, and someone’s reordering 32-bit words, but NSImageView displays it correctly. In fact, changing the `CGBitmapInfo` to `[.byteOrder32Big]` fixes this problem, but I still don’t get why NSImageView displays things correctly, or why big works when the architecture is little (even though PNG and TIFF may both work in big-endian 32-bit words).

Comment: "I'm writing a scanner app using ImageCaptureCore"  I suppose it's not something that everybody must have.  I have never heard of ImageCaptureCore.  "when I save the CGImage as PNG"  For what purpose?  I have never seen anybody trying saving an object as CGImage.

Comment: I am having trouble loading 8-bit gray level PNG's using `[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: png_path]`  Color image load fine. Even if I save a gray level PNG with Preview NSImage still doesn't like it.